# scroll to top of a bootstrap modal on click of a button in modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content login conatct_main" id="mdlcont">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button id="registrsubmit" name="registrsubmit" value="true" class="friends_log pull-right">Register</button>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The modal is not scrolling to top after a click. I tried scrolltop() method. It is not working . Can anyone help me on this?
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 5):

Wow! What a coincidence, I just did this today morning. What you need to do is:

```
// Before calling the modal window...
$("#modalId").scrollTop(0);
```

Also by using the BootStrap's modal window events API, you can do this:

```
$('#modalId').on('shown', function() {
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
})
```

Comment: I tried this before. But i have a long modal. So when i click a button in modal , i want to go to top of the modal.

Comment: This does the work, no matter what size the modal is!

Comment: please see the screenshot.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
 $("#myModal .modal-dialog").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

Comment: $("#myModal.modal-body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); if a modal box is used instead of a dialog box

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your image I'm guessing you're wanting to reposition the modal itself to move it off of the screen, as opposed to moving the viewport (which is what scrollTop would do). Check out [jQuery's offset function](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset-coordinates). For example, you could do

```
$('#foo').offset({
    top:-$('#foo').outerHeight()
});
```

Or if you want a smooth scrolling action, use the [animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#foo').animate({
    top:-$('#foo').outerHeight()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the click event of the button add the relevant jQuery code... I have added that for you.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content login conatct_main" id="mdlcont">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button id="registrsubmit" name="registrsubmit" value="true" class="friends_log pull-right" onclick="$("#modal-content").scrollTop(0);">Register</button>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On bootstrap v5.1.2,
if you have already allowed scrolling by adding the tag `modal-dialog-scrollable`, simply target the modal body as shown below:

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').scrollTop(0);
```

This worked for me